# I'm looking for this lemma about the nat type

Tags: coq

I'm looking for this lemma about nats. I'm hoping it already exists in one of the Coq libraries so I don't have to prove it.

```
forall m n : nat, (S m < n)%nat -> (n - (S m) < n)%nat
```

Please point me to the library if it exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost looking for `Nat.sub_lt`.  I recommend using the `Search` command to find lemmas.  It's quite powerful.

```
Require Import Arith.
Goal forall m n, (S m < n)%nat -> (n - (S m) < n)%nat.
  intros.
  Search (_ - _ < _).
  apply Nat.sub_lt.
  Search (_ < _ -> _ <= _).
  apply Nat.lt_le_incl, H.
  Search (0 < S _).
  apply Nat.lt_0_succ.
Qed.
```

or `auto using Nat.sub_lt, Nat.lt_le_incl, Nat.lt_0_succ.` or `auto with arith.`

Comment: Thanks! Especially for the advice on using ```Search``` - it's going to be useful as I continue trying to prove stuff.

Answer (score 3):

This statement does not hold: substituting `m = 0`, the conclusion becomes `n < n`, a clear contradiction.

Comment: Oops I overgeneralized my statement. Edited my question to correct this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no Coq library to prove your statement. So you can come up with your own proof as:

```
Require Import PeanoNat List.
Import Nat.

Goal(forall m n : nat, (S m < n)%nat -> (n - (S m) < n)%nat).
Proof.
induction m.
destruct n.
intros.
inversion H.
intros. simpl.
rewrite Nat.sub_0_r.
apply lt_succ_diag_r.
intros.
intuition.
Qed.
```